# Discord.py Slash command permissions error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm making a bot using slash commands however i tried to make a kick command

this is the code i've used

```
@client.tree.command(description = "kick a user")
@app_commands.describe(member = "who am i kicking", reason = "why am i kicking them")
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(interaction: discord.Interaction, member : discord.Member, reason: str=None):
  await member.kick(reason=reason)
  await interaction.response.send_message(f'Kicked {member.mention} for {reason}', ephemeral=True)
```

and the permissions line doesn't work (anyone can kick people)
does anyone know why this is or what i've done wrong?

Comment: Have you guaranteed that normal people can't already kick people through the discord website/app?

Comment: every role in my server (including @everyone) can't kick or ban

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have an app command and not a prefix command.
You should use `@app_commands.checks.has_permissions()` instead of `@commands.has_permissions()`.

[Here is the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions)

Everything else looks good.